# Finder/ osascript asks for SMB login even though the unlocked login Keychain has them

Tags: applescript, keychain

I have a cron script which includes

```
osascript -e 'mount volume "'$smbVolumeUrl'"'
```

When the script runs, a Finder popup asks for my credentials for the mount volume. I enter them, and the script continues successfully.

Before confirming, I also tick the 'remember my credentials' box. I can then see in Keychain that the correct network path and account name and password have been saved.

And still … the next time the script runs it asks again for credentials.

How can I stop it asking for credentials each time?

Comment: Is this a user cron entry or a system entry?  Obviously the latter is NOT going to know anything about user credentials ...

Comment: You may want to try `diskutil mount` instead.

Comment: Yes it's user cron. It used to all work but had my MacBook wiped last month for repair and now I have this

Comment: I think conventional wisdom has it that `osascript mount` knows how to talk to KeyChain but `diskutil mount` doesn't, which leaves you having to make up a solution for supplying the SMB network password

Comment: This may have been just a typo -- the different between smb://servername/ and smb://servername.local/ so maybe I'll just delete this question